# How to load a webpage in a visual designer?

Tags: ajax, web-services

I'd like to load a webpage and be able to change it, much like the A/B testing tools do.

How is that done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an IDE with visual page editor. You can do it in Dreamweaver (the best, costs $$$, is easiers to use for non-coder), Visual Studio Web Development. Netbeans and Eclipse with right plug-ins will do the trick.

---

For an online solution you can try http://www.online-html-editor.org/

If you want it to be on your servers look into http://www.openwebware.com/ - this is open source wysiwyg

Comment: I want that online. Be able to do that in a website.